# PayPal adaptive payment chained payment error

Tags: php, paypal

I am using PayPal adaptive payment chained payment i am Siteeweb owner i want receive all amount and get my commission and send the seller his amount.
i am using my email as primary and secendary but i get this error from payal

ERROR Code: 579040 
ERROR Message: Receiver PayPal accounts must be unique.

this is my php.

```
$url = trim("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay");
 $API_UserName = "intertrad-facilitator_api1.hotmail.fr"; //TODO
 $API_Password = "1393324018"; //TODO
 $API_Signature = "An5ns1Kso7MWUdW4ErQKJJJ4qi4-A5cIBBZt3.MeJSVSebRJv6lINDlR"; //TODO
 $receiver_email = "intertrad-facilitator@hotmail.fr"; //TODO
 $receiver_email1 = "intertrad_dz@hotmail.fr"; //TODO
 $receiver_email2 = "intertrad-facilitator@hotmail.fr"; //TODO
 $amount = 15; //TODO
 $AffiliateAmount = 5;
 $selleramount = 10;
 //Default App ID for Sandbox
 $API_AppID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";
 $API_RequestFormat = "NV";
 $API_ResponseFormat = "NV";
            $bodyparams = array ("requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US",
              "actionType" => "PAY_PRIMARY",
              "returnUrl" => "http://localhost/success.php",
              "cancelUrl" => "http://localhost/index.php",
              "currencyCode" => "USD",
              "feesPayer"=>"EACHRECEIVER",
              "memo"=>"Example",
              "receiverList.receiver(0).email" => $receiver_email,
              "receiverList.receiver(0).primary"=> "true",
              "receiverList.receiver(0).amount" => $amount,
              "receiverList.receiver(1).email" => $receiver_email1,
              "receiverList.receiver(1).primary"=> "false",
              "receiverList.receiver(1).amount" => $selleramount,
              "receiverList.receiver(2).email" => $receiver_email,
              "receiverList.receiver(2).primary"=> "false",
              "receiverList.receiver(2).amount" => $AffiliateAmount,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with PayPal's API and I since I don't have enough points to comment I'll need to do this as an answer.
I think the error is caused because you added the $receiver_email twice. You paired it with (2).email and (0).email, that's presumably not allowed.